grid search with scikit learn is not using the configured logger when n_jobs set
I'm trying to do gridsearch using scikit learn. I want to speed up the gridsearch so I set n_jobs to -1 and set parallel_backend context to loky. But when I use multiprocessing, all the logs from scikit learn are coming to console. it's not using my file-handler logger which logs to specific log file so as to keep console logs clean with few logs.
Can someone please help how to log the scikit-learn logs to a logfile when doing gridsearch with multiprocessing.
with parallel_backend("loky", n_jobs=N_JOBS):
    grid_search_log = get_proc_logger("grid_search")
    grid_search_log.info("%s grid search start", algorithm)
    sys.stderr = grid_search_log.logger.handlers[0].stream
    sys.stdout = grid_search_log.logger.handlers[0].stream
    try:
        grid_model.fit(data['x'].copy(), data['y'].copy())
    finally:
        sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
    grid_search_log.info("%s grid search complete", algorithm)

I tried setting system stdout and stderr to the filehandler of my logger object. That didn't worked.
I am expecting to log all scikit learn gridsearch related logs to a seperate log file rather than spamming the console.
